# dynamically load parial list in _Layout razor (master)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, repository, partial

I am having trouble with a _Partial in the master _Layout.

My _MemberList (Partial) have its own ViewModel (MemberListViewModel)
and I want to load this Partial in the _Layout maybe through a BaseController with a Layout Attribute or something, which is the best solution for this ?

The _MemberList is dynamically loaded, it depends on what the user selects.

It worked before when I had a strongly typed ViewModel in the _Layout, but when I try to load other ViewModels it asks for the one in the _Layout, so I guess I have to find another solution for this.

So what I need is a "dynamically loaded list in the _Layout(master) using a _partial".

Sample would be great!

Thanx

Comment: Why you do not use instead @Html.RenderAction to load data from your controller?

Comment: I have tried that, but i get "Expression must return a value to render". Any ideas ?

Comment: update your question with the expression that gives you grief :)